# How to include a specific php file when a div is shown/display:"block"

Tags: php, javascript, html, include, show-hide

I have a webpage with 20 forms on it.

They are all hidden until you select a form from the drop down box and then the form will appear.

Each form has its own validation. The problem is I've included the validation for each form in its own div with each specific form.

So I thought because each div was hidden the validation for all other hidden forms won't work ... How wrong was I :|

Any way to only include the php file include when the div is not hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: the web does not work that way.

Longer answer: The browser doesn't include PHP, the server includes it and spits out all the output in HTML to the browser. The browser just sees the HTML output so it sees and sends everything.

There are a couple of solutions. I would recommend making sure each of your divs has it's own form tag and then adding a hidden input to each one so that your PHP script can decide what validation it's supposed to do. Something like this:

```
<div id="formfoo">
<form method="POST" action="/your-script.php">
<input type="hidden" name="validate" value="formfoo" />
<!-- rest of your form -->
</form>
</div>
```

Then in PHP:

```
if( $_POST['validate'] == 'formfoo' ) {
    // validate fields in formfoo here.
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, clear as day. Think you've given me an idea. The problem was I already called a script when posting the form, but why not just put each php validation include within the .php script im calling in when posting the form. Best of both worlds eh...

Comment: Ok I need some help, the validation MUST appear BEFORE the form is sent, so putting it in the post section WONT work as it says header cannot be modified once sent. I never had this issue before I put it as an include in the post so I assume it is this. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you show some of your code? Generally it's better to separate your logic (validation) from your display code.

Answer (score 3):

Since the php has allready been processed to send all the content to the browser you can only work with javascript. The way to do it would be to bind the validation of the forms to onsubmit of that specific form, so the event would only fire for the correct form.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has no conception of what is visible on the client size or what is not.  You'll have to think of a different approach.

Fortunately, there are alternative methods.

As each div contains a form, you can simply have all the forms contains a hidden field (say formid, or something) that you can check to determine which form was submitted.

Alternatively, you could give every submit control on your forms a unique name, and check the name of the submit button that was triggered on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

additional tip:

you could set the form elements in the hidden `div`s to disabled :

```
<input type="text" name="bla" disabled="disabled" />
```

and enable them via javascript once they are shown.

disabled elements are not send when the form is submitted.

....the handling of the disabling/enabling may well be much more effort than seperating the forms and making the distinction serversite like Cfreak suggested...